# Use multiple domains with a single IP and single EAR in Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a web application (deployed as an EAR). It is serving customers which navigate to: `http://aaa.com` . I now want to release a second web application with a domain: `bbb.com` .

The two web applications use much of the same code, but serve very different customers. What is the best way to have both of these applications deployed at once. Ideally, I would be able to use a single IP address and use the HTTP request headers to split traffic between the web applications.

My initial thought is to put two WARs inside the single EAR and create a Glassfish virtual server which sends visitors to the different wars depending on which IP address traffic is received (however, I can't see how to do this without using two IP addresses or serving one of the applications on a different port).

Comment: Seems easy, just put an Apache in front of it and map the requests to the 2 different contexts....I don't see any problem with that!?

Comment: I want to use my already installed web server rather than install another. Especially given that Glassfish can probably solve the problem somehow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> Because the virtual server cannot specify an HTTP listener that is
>   already being used by another virtual server...

This is what lead me to believe that two IPs or two different ports would be required (note: HTTP listeners must have unique IP:port pairs).

However, I have tried having two virtual servers use the same HTTP listener and it works fine.

I followed this guide to set up the servers: http://hobione.wordpress.com/2008/10/02/glassfish-virtual-server/

Comment: Quick tip: you will have to create a local entry in your DNS if you want to test on localhost.